# Where is this element?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, magento2, web-inspector, htmlelements

Good day all. I've inspected my page and found the particular element and I wish to style out or delete but it seems not to be attached to any document or sheet in my website, yet it appears automatically on every product page.

I have tried adding visibility: hidden !important to the div element but I don't know where or how or what to make this a reality for me.

Please help me!!!

web url sample of a product page: https://tucsons.ng/index.php/angelo-galasso.html

screenshot of the particular element = [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be generated by some code in Magento and thus hard to find in the theme code base. But have you tried to search in the code base for the id name `product-addtocart-button`?

It is still very possible to CSS style this element without having access to the html element itself. In the image below I have here changed the color to blue with CSS only.

[image]

EDIT: Misunderstood which element you wanted to hide. Sorry about that. You should be able to completely hide it like this in your CSS:

```css
    div.product.pricing {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks anatolhiman, however, the particular element i want to edit out is that "angelo gallaso is available to buy at increment of 1"

Comment: @FrankTobi Sorry, misread your post! See my edit in the original answer, you should be able to hide it with plain CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but where? how? which particular source

The div does not have any style sheet or connecting dots

Comment: Do you have access to modify any modified CSS file at all in this codebase? Or do you have access to change CSS in the Magento admin panel, maybe? (sorry I don't know much about this system). If you don't have access to write and publish CSS then you need to find someone who has this access to files and the server where they are located. You can basically add the snippet from me above in any of the many .css files on the server, for example in this one: https://tucsons.ng/pub/static/version1627952002/frontend/Sm/smartech/en_US/css/pages-theme.css

Comment: i had to declare